# How to make the raw rnn emit custom outputs not the defaults?

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

According to [Tensorflow documentation for raw RNN](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/raw_rnn) you may set the cell_output at your own shape for the initial time step, when time=0 in order to emit your own outputs.

Currently, it only works if we set initial (for time=0) cell output to None and the rest of the emitted cell outputs equal to the previous cell output, but this is not what we want. We want our own outputs to be emitted and not the internal state of the RNN cell.

Here is the related source code:

```
    def get_loop_fn(self, encoder_final_state, eos_token, batch_size, WW, bb):
    def loop_fn(time, previous_output, previous_state, previous_loop_state):
        # inputs:  time, previous_cell_output, previous_cell_state, previous_loop_state
        # outputs: elements_finished, input, cell_state, output, loop_state

        if previous_state is None:  # time == 0
            assert previous_output is None
            return self.loop_fn_initial(encoder_final_state=encoder_final_state, eos_token=eos_token,
                                        batch_size=batch_size)
        else:
            return self.loop_fn_transition(previous_cell_output=previous_output, previous_cell_state=previous_state,
                                           batch_size=batch_size, WW=WW, bb=bb)

    return loop_fn

def loop_fn_initial(self, encoder_final_state, eos_token, batch_size):
    # https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/raw_rnn
    # here we have a static rnn case so all length so be taken into account,
    # so I guess they are all False always
    # From documentation: a boolean Tensor of shape [batch_size]
    initial_elements_finished = self.all_elems_non_finished(batch_size=batch_size)

    initial_input = eos_token
    initial_cell_state = encoder_final_state

    # initial_cell_output = None
    # give it the shape that we want:
    initial_cell_output = tf.constant(np.zeros(shape=(batch_size, self.TARGET_FEATURE_LEN)), dtype=tf.float32)

    initial_loop_state = None  # we don't need to pass any additional information

    return (initial_elements_finished,
            initial_input,
            initial_cell_state,
            initial_cell_output,
            initial_loop_state)

def loop_fn_transition(self, previous_cell_output, previous_cell_state, batch_size, WW, bb):
    """note that the matrix W is going to be shared among outputs"""
    print "previous cell output"
    print previous_cell_output
    print

    finished = self.all_elems_non_finished(batch_size=batch_size)  # (time >= decoder_lengths)
    # this operation produces boolean tensor of [batch_size] defining if corresponding sequence has ended

    # this is always false in our case so just comment next two lines
    # finished = tf.reduce_all(elements_finished)  # -> boolean scalar
    # input = tf.cond(finished, lambda: pad_step_embedded, get_next_input)
    next_input = tf.add(tf.matmul(previous_cell_output, WW), bb)

    next_cell_state = previous_cell_state
    emit_output = next_input,  # previous_cell_output

    next_loop_state = None  # we don't need to pass any additional information

    return (finished,
            next_input,
            next_cell_state,
            emit_output,
            next_loop_state)
```

And this is the error message that we get when trying to create the graph:

> ValueError: The two structures don't have the same nested structure.
>   First structure: , second structure: (,).

Any ideas would be welcome